# Datasets in other but root folder of the project not visible in VS2010 reporting

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, dataset, directory, root

[image]

I am trying to create a report but I am not able to see any datasets that are not in the root folder of the project. However I want the datasets to sit somewhere deeper and not make a huge pile of files in the root folder. With the green color I marked visible dataset(which is in a root folder) while the red one is the one which is invisible. Now I try to chose a dataset for Report1.rdlc, but all I see are the datasets from the root folder and not the ones that are in  the same folder as the report is. Moreover when trying to create a dataset, it puts it in the root folder without asking and once i drag it into other place (NewFolder1), it becomes invisible. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After huge amount of time wasted I found the solution - it is actually a bug in VS 2010 and was fixed in VS 2010 SP1, thus installing it would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I just ran into this in SP1 as well and was able to get the new Dataset to show up in the list only after stopping and restarting Visual Studio 2010.  I hope this helps.